# SOLVED - How to add a condition when the http response of given URL is err -1 or 7 in Flutter (getting an error getting images)

Tags: flutter, dart, http, flutter-dependencies, flutter-http

I'm creating a flutter news app, using this API https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines

Everything runs well when I select the 'us' country to fetch the news, but, when I switch to 've' (Venezuela) I realize that some of the news comes from sources that are banned in my country, when I try to fetch the image of the news, it dropped me an err -1 or err 7 from the http package and the app stops.

I'm following the null-safety coding practices and also using a Model for processing the data that comes from the API. I already check the internet connection of my Virtual Android Device. I'm sure that the problem is due to the banned domains that the API provides. The primary approach is to check the http response of the URL given so I can prevent the App to get stuck or bugged.

This is my flutter doctor response:

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.6, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.19043.2130], locale es-VE)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.3)

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)

[√] VS Code (version 1.73.0)

[√] Connected device (4 available)

[√] HTTP Host Availability

The code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:news/src/models/news_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:news/src/services/api_key.dart';

const _urlNews = 'https://newsapi.org/v2';
const _apiKey = apiKey;

class NewsService with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Article> headlines = [];
  NewsService() {
    getTopHeadlines();
  }

  getTopHeadlines() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('$_urlNews/top-headlines?apiKey=$_apiKey&country=ve&pageSize=100');
    final resp = await http.get(url);

    final newsResponse = NewsResponse.fromJson(resp.body);

    headlines.addAll(newsResponse.articles);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```
class _CardImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Article news;

  const _CardImage({required this.news});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(50), bottomRight: Radius.circular(50)),
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1),
            child: (news.urlToImage != '')
                ? FadeInImage(
                    placeholder: const AssetImage('assets/img/giphy.gif'),
                    image: NetworkImage('${news.urlToImage}'),
                  )
                : const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/img/no-image.png'))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A screenshot of the error:

[image]

I want to add a conditional at this point to show a placeholder image that says something like 'this is banned' or 'didn't load' when the http package couldn't get it, but I don't know where.

The app is for learning purposes, I don't want to show anything that is legally banned by any internet provider inside the list of news, or couldn't load the resource because the host of the image didn't work.

Thank you in advance!

**Solution 09/11/2022:**

I change my Widget builder to this:

```
class _CardImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Article news;

  const _CardImage({required this.news});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(50), bottomRight: Radius.circular(50)),
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1),
            child: (news.urlToImage != '')
                ? FadeInImage(
                    placeholder: const AssetImage('assets/img/giphy.gif'),
                    image: NetworkImage('${news.urlToImage}'),
                    imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                      return const Text('Error loading');
                    }
                  )
                : const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/img/no-image.png'))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using the imageErrorBuilder property of the FadeInImage. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with response.statusCode.
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: Oh, nice! I couldn't find this, I will try, and if works I'll update and tag you, thanks!

Comment: thank you! I just fixed it using the imageErrorBuilder property of the FadeInImage. I tried checking the response object and it comes a little bit messy due to the API responses (sometimes it doesn't return any image URL either). But it's something I'll apply for the next stuff and is a big learning. Thanks again @user20453481